# How do I connect to a Red Hat Server using the rdp protocol?

Tags: linux, redhat, rdp

Is it possible and if so how can I connect to a Red Hat server using the rdp protocol?  Not interested in using VNC for a variety of reasons.

Comment: Just curious - why not VNC via a SSH tunnel?  I know you said you had a variety of reasons, just wanted to know what the show-stoppers were...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, there's [xrdp](http://xrdp.sourceforge.net/).  I don't get the impression that it's a mature project, but it's worth a try.

Comment: +1 - xrdp is about the only thing out there for Linux. RDP is a pretty proprietary protocol, unfortunately.

Answer (score 2):

Another alternative to VNC is to export X11 apps from the server to your desktop.

Install an X server like [Xming](http://www.straightrunning.com/XmingNotes/) on your workstation. Now use putty to connect to the server. Make sure you Enable X-11 forwarding by checking the box in `Settings > SSH > X11`. (If you use a command line SSH client just type `ssh -X`)

Now, from the terminal on the server type the name of the command you'd like to use. The program should appear on your desktop.

Answer (score 0):

Like **chaos** pointed out a bit earlier there's always xrdp. However, have you considered [NX](http://nomachine.com) (free as in beer for 2 connections, libraries free as in speech) or its fully free as in speech cousin [FreeNX](http://freenx.berlios.de/)? I've been using NX for three years now and am fully satisfied.

Answer (score 0):

In windows the supported main supported rdp is called rdp. In linux, its called X11 forwarding.

```
ssh -Y
```

or

```
ssh -X
```